# Помогите с отношение многие ко многим Django

Tags: python, django

```
class Event (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   date = models.DateField(default='')
   dicript = models.CharField(max_length=300,default='Описание отсутствует')
   category = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   adress = models.TextField(max_length=100)
   website = models.URLField(max_length=100,default='Web-сайт отсутствует')   
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="creator",null=True)
   subs = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="subs")

@classmethod
def make_sub (cls,current_user,sub_event):
    event, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        current_user = user
    )
    event.subs.add(sub_event)
```

**Пытаюсь создать подписку на событие через консоль, выдает ошибку
Вызываю метод Make_Sub передаю user и event, на которое надо подписаться - выдает ошибку invalid field name(s) for model Event: 'current_user'.**

Comment: Ну ведь у вас на самом деле такого поля нет

Comment: Поля current_user?

Comment: Угу, у вас есть поле user и переменная current_user в методе, а поля current_user нету

Comment: Значит в методе нужно user = current_user?

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь создать модель с несуществующим полем.
Правильным будет:

```
@classmethod
def make_sub (cls,current_user,sub_event):
    event, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        user = user  # Здесь надо исправить. Теперь пользователя вы присваиваете полю user в модели Event
    )
    event.subs.add(sub_event)
```

Comment: но теперь мне нельзя добавить событие
Ошибка : OperationalError at /admin/events/event/add/
                                        no such table: events_event_subs

Comment: rumor, я не знаю. У вас там на subs указано отношение к user, вообще. А ошибку выдаёт, что нет такой таблицы. Если сложно с такими вещами, то возможно вам было бы лучше вернуться к основам.